# PXe M0F and efi boot problem after ubuntu 14.04 install through efi

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, uefi

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo g500,I am a bit new to terminal.
I previously had windows 8(My laptop came with FREE DOS per-installed) on my laptop and decide to change it with Ubuntu. I booted through EFI using a normal installation disc(normal booting did not respond to the disc). The installation went without a single error but the problems started after the first boot, After the install I only have Ubuntu installed and no other OS!

I started getting the following error:

Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997 - 2000 Intel Corporation

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.0.2.3(05/18/10)

Check cable connection!
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.

and that is it! it does not ask me insert a boot-media like in the other question and the grub loads up after this and i only get 3 options

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced options(This is where is get the recovery option)
3. System setting(A.K.A bios setting)
   and after this is Ubuntu Loads normally. I can't boot through any other now as my EFI is occupied by Ubuntu and also if i try to boot through my DVD-rom it gives me the PXE M0F error and loads the grub again.

NOTE: I previously had the LOW GRAPHICS MODE issue and solved it using NOMODESET.

I would like to solve the PXE M0F error so that i can install Windows or maybe reinstall ubuntu again neatly!

Thanks in advance for all your support!

Comment: I second bain's suggestion for getting past the PXE-boot problem. For your other problem (an inability to boot Windows), it could be that GRUB hasn't detected Windows, which should be easy to fix; or it could be that you've accidentally wiped Windows out, which will be harder to fix. It's impossible to know without more data. To that end, please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and post back with the URL to your document on that site.

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS look at "Configuration" screen and set "PXE Boot To LAN" to Disabled.